# ActiveRecord: Find where column is nil or empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an array column in postgres and I want to find all the records where this column is either `nil` or `[]`. I can search one or the other fine but trying both fails.

This is what I attempted

```
Model.where(column: [nil, []])
```

But I get the error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{NULL,{}}")
DETAIL:  Unexpected "{" character.
```

Comment: which version of Rails are you using ?

Comment: Empty array column in postgres is selected with `'{}'`. That said: `Model.where(column: [nil, "'{}'"])`.

Comment: @mudasobwa I don't think that will help, that would just end up with a different problem with `{NULL, '{}'}`, no?

Comment: @muistooshort ah, indeed; the main point of my comment was a hint on how to select the empty array in postgres; I never trust AR to build queries due to too much magic and accidental failures on complicated queries.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This worked for me

```
Model.where('column IS NULL OR column = ?', '{}')
```

Comment: Right. The underlying problem is that `where(column: [nil, a])` usually means `column is null or column = a` but, since `column` is an array and ActiveRecord knows it, it tries to say `column = '{some confused nonsense}'`. You could also look at `array_length(coalesce(column, array[])) is null`.

Comment: Nice work @Qwertie. If you don't mind me asking what did you use an array column for?

Comment: @DaryllSantos It's probably not the best solution but when I have records that can be tagged I use an int array for the tag IDs as it seems a bit much to create a new table to hold the tag ID and the taggable ID. Really I should be making the column non null and setting the default to []

Answer (score -1):

```
Model.where("column = ? OR column = ?", nil, [])
```

This will execute SQL query

```
SELECT "models".* FROM "models" WHERE (column = NULL OR column = NULL)
```

But you need can do this only by

```
Model.where("column = ?", nil)
```

Comment: Have you checked this? I doubt even `"column = ?", nil` would work correctly.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Shows no results when I can see there are a few with nil and [].